# Node.js unit testing: Test behaviour when fs module throws error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

How can you test the behaviour of a module when an `fs` module function throws an error? I have this code:

```
fs.stat('/Users/' + username.sync() + '/Library/LaunchAgents/' + key + '.plist', function(error, stat) {

 if (!error) {
   callback(null, true);
 } else if (error.code == 'ENOENT') {
   callback(null, false);
 } else {
   callback(error, null);
 }

 return;
});
```

But currently, the `else` path is never run during tests. What would be the best-practise way to cover this line?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to fiddle around with actual files, you could use a module like `sinon` for stubbing `fs`. That way, you can make the `fs.stat` callback being called with an error of your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of common system errors here: https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors You can use the description to trigger some errors. You can't test all of them but there are easy ones, for example, change the permissions of a file and you'll have an *EACCES* error.